# What is the difference between pending and active notifications using the Flutter Local Notification Plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, uilocalnotification

Throughout my app I am creating notifications, that work but when I use this: ***flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation()?.getActiveNotifications();***

I get zero active notifications but when I use this:
***flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();***

I find all my local notifications are pending rather than active?
Is this correct, I am not sure about the difference between pending and active notifications using the Flutter Local Notification Plugin.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**
Active notifications are notification running currently (you should be seeing the notification).
Pending notifications are notifications that are scheduled to happen in the future.